# Qt/C++ How to get foreign keys for a table in different databases

Tags: c++, database, qt, foreign-keys, cross-database

I am creating an app using Qt/C++, which should be able to connect to different types of databases and get it's structure and info from there. And regarding DB structure I've found methods how to get list of tables and their columns without knowledge of DB type, using something like that:

```
QSqlDatabase db_ = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase(dbType);
db_.setDatabaseName(dbName);
db_.setUserName(user);
db_.setPassword(password);
db_.setHostName(hostName);
db_.setPort(port);

QStringList tables = db_.tables();

auto driver = db_.driver();
QSqlRecord record = driver->record(tableName);
QStringList fields;

for (int i = 0; i < record.count(); i++) {
    fields.append(record.field(i).name());
}
```

But I can't find any method to get the foreign keys in a table without using direct queries to DB. I would be very thankful for your help.

Comment: The functionality for this in Qt is fairly limited, there are some utility functions like tables http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#tables and primaryIndex http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#primaryIndex but nothing for foreignkeys. Depending on which databases you want to support querying the information schema https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_schema might be a reasonable solution for this.